# Swift: Reflecting properties of subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, reflection, nsmanagedobject, mirror

When accessing the inner structure of a subclass of NSManagedObject using a Mirror, all managed variables are ignored.

```
public class Foo: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var bar: String?
}

var f: Foo = ...
// ... creating a Foo in a valid context ...

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: f)
for c in mirror.children {        // children count == 0
  print("\(c.label!):\(c.value)") // never executed
}
```

How can reflection mechanisms used on NSManagedObjects.

Answer (score 8):

The accessor methods for Core Data properties are synthesized
dynamically at runtime.

You can enumerate the attributes of a Core Data entity using
the `entity` property of `NSManagedObject` which is a `NSEntityDescription`
and has a `attributesByName` property.

A simple example:

```
for (name, attr) in  newManagedObject.entity.attributesByName {
    let attrType = attr.attributeType // NSAttributeType enumeration for the property type
    let attrClass = attr.attributeValueClassName ?? "unknown"
    print(name, "=", newManagedObject.valueForKey(name), "type =", attrClass)
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Actually I need the type of the children, even if they are nil. The hint with the entity leads in that direction.

Comment: @Guardian667: You can get the type from the attribute description as well.

Comment: The NSAttributeDescription has a member of NSAttributeType enum. How can the real datatype kind of Any.Type be determined, without implementing a mapping between NSAttributeType and Any.Type.
Also: What if the NSManagedObject-SubClass holds a member which is also a subclass of NSManagedObject. It'll be quiet complicated to find a mapping from NSAttributeType to the special one.

Comment: @Guardian667: `attributeType` gives the type as defined in the Core Data model inspector as an enumeration. `attributeValueClassName` give the name of the class which is used to represent the object. Members which are also managed objects are *relationships* and can also be enumerated with `relationshipsByName`. – What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm deserializing objects. The needed values from the serialized object are determined by investigating the `Children`of the `Mirror` of the target class, e.G. `deserialize<T:NSObject>(serialized: String, type: T.Type)`. Everything works fine, until subclasses of NSManagedObject are used. (At least) two reasons: a) My algorithm needs the `NSObject`s default constructor, which is hidden by `NSManagedObject`. b) NSManagedObject synthesizes properties dynamically at runtime, as you said, so the mirror holds no children.