# Reflection in Swift, children value is 0 if type is NSNumber

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to print the values of the properties in my Data object.
If the property type is NSNumber, the value printed is 0 (not the correct value), while if the property is NSDate the date gets printed correctly.
Here is the code i'm using

```
let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: data)
  for children in mirrored_object.children {
     print("\(children.value)")
  }
}
```

Here is the Data object

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Data: Object {

    dynamic var timestamp : NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude : NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var latitude : NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var altitude: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var speed: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var course: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var horizontalAccuracy: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var accelX: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var accelY: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var accelZ: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var rotX: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var rotY: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var rotZ: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var magnetX: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var magnetY: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var magnetZ: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var brightness: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var proximity: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var movement: NSNumber = 0.0
    dynamic var trackingType: NSString = ""
}
```

Why does it print 0 as the value of my properties?

Comment: You should show us how `data` is defined

Comment: It looks like all the properties are populated with `0`. So which value did you expect?

Comment: Yeah those are the default value but then they get overwritten

Comment: So if you simply write `print(data.timestamp)` you get a value different from zero while the reflection code returns `0`?

Comment: Yeah just tested. It seems like it is printing the default values instead of the ones it has

Comment: I tested your code with the only difference that I removed the inheritance from `Object` and it is working fine for me. Could you perform the same test? (I mean removing the `: Object` part from `Data`).

Comment: The `Object` inheritance is needed for Realm

Comment: I understand, I just want to check if that is the problem. Could you just perform a quick test?

Comment: I have no experience with Realm, but I assume that Swift mirroring does not work with dynamic properties, where the accessor methods are created at runtime. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411934/swift-reflecting-properties-of-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject, a similar observation was made for Core Data properties which are also dynamically created.

Comment: I have tried to remove `dynamic` but got the same results. Removing the `Object` inheritance breaks the whole project but that has to be the issue